# How to scale bounds to the Qpicture in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, bounds

I'm trying to set the bounds of this PyQtGraph candlestick chart to properly zoom in so it views the candlesticks as something other than a tiny spec on the chart that I need to zoom in to.
This works fine if the value of t (time) is a full integer, but if I use a value such as 1.00001, 1.00002, ect the candle sticks become a tiny dot and it does not automatically scale.
I struggle to understand how bounding works due to lack of quality documentation however I think I get the jist of it enough to know that

```
QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())
```

should automatically scale the bounds to the picture that is drawn.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot, QtCore, QtGui

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

'''chart items'''
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.flagHasData = False

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data 
        self.flagHasData = True
        self.generatePicture()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()
        


    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open))
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())
        
        
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

data = [  
    [1.00001, 1.00569 , 1.00577, 1.00560, 1.00578],
    [1.00002, 1.00577, 1.00571 , 1.00579, 1.00540],
]

        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
item = CandlestickItem()
item.set_data(data)
plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # window = Window()    
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Can someone explain to me why it is not working?
Would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html#boundingRect) of QPicture is a QRect, which is integer based. If you print out the result, even after converting it to a QRectF, you will see that it will be:

```
QRect(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Which corresponds to the visible range in the view.

This clearly won't work out, because all those rectangles are actually very small.

The solution is to provide a rectangle that *precisely* maps the contents. To achieve so, you can create a temporary QPainterPath, add the lines and rectangles to it, and store the bounding rect of that path so that you can return it when the new picture is generated:

```py
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    _boundingRect = QtCore.QRectF()
    # ...
    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            line = QtCore.QLineF(t, min, t, max)
            path.moveTo(line.p1())
            path.lineTo(line.p2())
            p.drawLine(line)

            rect = QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open)
            path.addRect(rect)

            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(rect)

        p.end()
        self._boundingRect = path.boundingRect()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect
```